# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() when using sop.brute

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.6

I use the Python3.6 and I've been confused about this question for a long time..so here is my code.

```
def fo(x,y):
    z=np.sin(x)+0.05*x**2+np.cos(y)+0.05*y**2
    if output == True:
        print("%8.4f %8.4f %8.4f" % (x,y,z))
        return z

import scipy.optimize as sop

sop.brute(fo,(-10,10.1,5),(-10,10.1,5),finish = None)
```

---

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-c7886e35ff4b>", line 1, in <module>
    sop.brute(fo,(-10,10.1,5),(-10,10.1,5),finish = None)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2811, in brute
    if len(lrange[k]) < 3:

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

here's another try:

```
r1=slice(-10,10.1,5)

r2=slice(-10,10.1,5)
sop.brute(fo,r1,r2,finish = None)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-230c07265998>", line 1, in <module>
    sop.brute(fo,r1,r2,finish = None)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2804, in brute
    N = len(ranges)
```

### TypeError: object of type 'slice' has no len()

```
sop.brute(fo,(r1,r2),finish = None)

TypeError: fo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I'm new to here and sorry if I ask a stupid question but I cant' work it out T.T thx a lot

Comment: int object don't have length, convert it to string if you need to find length of a integer object

Comment: You shouldn't paste your code in images. Just paste it into your question, select it and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: The second parameter in your `sop` call specifies the ranges. As the name says, each element in that tuple needs to be a range, not an integer. Did you mean to pass `[(-10, 10), (1, 5)]` instead?

Comment: I want to pass a range from -10 to 10.1 at the step 5 ,..when I add a '' and convert it to string it said that 'list' object has no attribute 'step',and if I use the [(-10, 10), (1, 5)],it said thatTypeError: fo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Answer (score 0):

```
def fo(p):
    x, y = p
    z = np.sin(x)+0.05*x**2+np.sin(y)+0.05*y**2
    if output == True:
        print('%8.4f %8.4f %8.4f' % (x,y,z))
    return z
```

unpack tuple like in the code

Comment: Please update your question, it does not have enough clues for us to know what should we answer